# JDT How to know the full name of a superclass

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin. I'm using the following implementation of an ASTVisitor in order to replace the superclass of a class if that class extends a third one.

```
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Name;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleType;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.Type;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration;

public class SuperClassVisitor extends ASTVisitor{
    public Type     superClass;
    public String   newSuperClass;
    private String  oldSuperClass;


    public SuperClassVisitor(String newType, String oldType) {
        this.newSuperClass = newType;
        this.oldSuperClass = oldType;
    }

    public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {
        superClass = node.getSuperclassType();
        if (newSuperClass != null) {
            Name oldName = node.getAST().newName(oldSuperClass);
            SimpleType oldType = node.getAST().newSimpleType(oldName);

            Name newName = node.getAST().newName(newSuperClass);
            SimpleType newType = node.getAST().newSimpleType(newName);

            if (superClass != null && superClass.equals(oldType)) {
                node.setSuperclassType(newType);                
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm visiting every single class in my project. Basically, in classes that extend `oldType`, I want to change it to `newType`. However, the condition `superClass.equals(oldType)` is never true because my `oldType` string is a dot-separated fully qualified name, while `node.getSuperclassType()` returns just the name of the class.

Is it possible to find out the full name of the superclass?

*For reference, this answered helped me create this visitor:*
[How Can a SuperClass name be retrieved from a java file using ASTParser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079407/how-can-a-superclass-name-be-retrieved-from-a-java-file-using-astparser)

Comment: Your question and title are slightly contradictory, I think...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to make it clearer.

Comment: For any non-array class, `TheClassName.class.getName()` will return the full dot-separated name as a String.  `someObj.getClass().getName()` will return the class name of an object.  `someObj.getClass().getSuperclass().getName()` will return the name of the superclass.

Comment: I'm not working with classes thought, but with compilation units.

Answer (score 4):

I may have misunderstood the question, but...

> my oldType string is a dot-separated fully qualified name, while node.getSuperclassType() returns just the name of the class.

This is wrong. Your code reads:

```
public Type     superClass;
<...>
SimpleType oldType = <...>
```

Nor `Type`, nor `SimpleType` subclass `String`. They are NOT names. They are fully qualified classes with information about types. And the reason they do not test for equals is written on the Javadoc on `Type.equals`:

> public final boolean equals(Object obj)
>   The ASTNode implementation of this Object method uses object identity (==). Use subtreeMatch to compare two subtrees for equality.

The latter also gives an indication on where to look for a proper equality tester. As to why the nodes gave different names - `toString` on `Type` says pretty clearly

> Returns a string representation of this node suitable for debugging purposes only.

so you cannot use it for any decision making.
I imagine you mixed `getName` and `toString` to get that result, since `getName` is not defined for `Type` and is defined for `SimpleType`, though that part of the code is missing, so I am only speculating.

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves Do you know a way of saying "Your understanding of the classes and methods involved is completely wrong, please read the (fairly simple) Javadoc" in detail while providing an answer and NOT sound condescending?

Comment: @JoãoGonçalves By ridiculous I certainly did not mean that the OP is stupid. Rather that I was skeptical that the issue I answered is in fact what the OP asked. The answer is too long to have been put into a comment, which is the usual in these cases. You are right though, I'll remove the possibly offending parts.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question though. I have a class with a superclass. I'm constructing a `Type` out of a string and there's nothing else I can do with it. I just wanted to know if it was possible to obtain the qualified name of the superclass. All I can find is it's *simple* name.

Comment: @ecc This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Either way, you have never actually shown how you get the names from the types, so I can't say why you are getting different ones.

Comment: I can try to explain it, but I think I'll just post another question.

Comment: The new/old class strings were read from a file, they were never types. The TypeDeclaration was obtained from parsing the source code.

Comment: Follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24079862/jdt-trying-to-know-the-qualified-name-of-a-super-class-type

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem.

It seems that the `SimpleType` can not resolved to `QulifiedType` automatically by JDT. Thus I would like to parse the import statements to get imported types firstly. 
I am also searching an easier solution.